# Replace Javascript with Bootstrap responsive slideshow

Tags: slideshow, responsive

I'm trying to find a nice looking bootstrap slideshow that looks similar to this one: https://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.slider

I would use the one in the link but it's got way to much Javascript and doesn't respond properly when I change the size of my window. Any ideas how I could create this using Bootstrap, HTML and CSS only? So it still needs to be automatic as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It’s the carousel you’re after, without knowing which version of bootstrap you’re on I cannot provide an example but you can find full examples for what you need in the bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/